# non zero exit code in Problem AE2B from SPOJ

Tags: java

I wrote a piece of code to solve this problem.

I keep getting NZEC (non zero exit code runtime error), but I can't find which part of the code can cause any Exception since it 
only involves simple arithmetic computation (there should be no chance of divided by zero).

The logic of the code doesn't matter, and I just wonder where the exception could be hiding.

Can any one spot any bug?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * SPOJ Problem Set (classical) 4302. (K,N)-Knight Problem code: AE2B
 * 
 * @author Eric
 * 
 */
public class AE2B {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        int count = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            String[] tokens = reader.readLine().split(" ");
            int k = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            int n = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            int x1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            int y1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
            int x2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
            int y2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]);

            int g = gcd(k, n);
            int dx = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            int dy = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
            if (g > 1) {
                if ((dx % g != 0) || (dy % g != 0)) {
                    System.out.println("NIE");
                    continue;
                }
                k /= g;
                n /= g;
                dx /= g;
                dy /= g;
            }
            if (k % 2 == 0 || n % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("TAK");
            } else if (dx % 2 + dy % 2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("NIE");
            } else {
                System.out.println("TAK");
            }
        }

    }

    static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (a < b) {
            return gcd(b, a);
        }
        if (b == 0) {
            return a;
        }
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "NZEC"? If you've got an exception, *where* have you got an exception? A stack trace would be useful, as would sample user input to demonstrate the problem...

Comment: Have a look at the input and make sure you are not getting integer overflow anywhere.  Negative numbers can do strange things in code that assumes positive numbers.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, NZEC in SPOJ means "Non Zero Exit Code", and this happens when your program encounters exceptions during execution.  Online judges like SPOJ only tells you that your program has met an exception, but will not reveal the stack trace or the exception name to you. You can only figure it out by yourself.

Comment: @Spirit: So do you not have any idea what the input might have been? For example, your code will barf on non-numeric input...

Comment: @rossum, the input range is between -10^9 and 10^9, which is alright for integer to hold. And this pgram makes no assumption of postive integer. Both positive and negative inputs are accepted.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, problems on SPOJ have rigid input formats and you can expect all the input to be valid, so what you mentioned will not be a problem. See the problem for yourself : https://www.spoj.pl/problems/AE2B/

Answer (score 0):

Using your gcd() method, I get a stack overflow error from:

```
gcd(-12, -17);
```

I suggest that you avoid calculating the GCD of negative numbers:

```
static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    a = Math.abs(a);
    b = Math.abs(b);
    if (a < b) {
        return gcd(b, a);
    }
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    }
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Comment: the problem description says "0 ≤ K, N ≤ 10^9", so k and n will not be negative. So what you mentioned should not be the reason.

Comment: The problem says: "0 ≤ K, N ≤ 10^9, K + N > 0".  As I read that, N may be negative, only the sum K + N is guaranteed positive.  If both were guaranteed positive then the "K + N > 0" part would be superfluous.

Comment: you're getting it wrong. K + N > 0 means K and N cannot be 0 at the same time. And the description does mean both K and N are within the given interval, because applying abs() to both K and N still gets NZEC.